# Accessing BasePage from Master Page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I'm adding a custom control dynamically in master page code-behind:

```
try
{
    // Add custom sidenav menu control dynamically
    SideNavMenu sidenav = new SideNavMenu();

    tempPath = Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
    path = tempPath.Contains(@"/sitename") ? tempPath.Substring(7) : tempPath;

    sidenav.MenuPath = path;
    menuPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(sidenav);
}
catch
{
    // Handle this - custom error form and email
    // Master page needs access to base page LogError method

}
```

This is the base page with ErrorLog() method, which actually generates an email:

```
public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void LogError(Exception error)
    {
        ...
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```

How can I call ErrorLog from master page code-behind? Or is there a better place to put the "common" ErrorLog method? Can someone suggest correct syntax or a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `LogError` function in a class in your App_Code folder and probably make it a static function. If it's reusable through multiple projects, then place it in a seperate class library. Your `BasePage` class has no business implementing the details of logging errors and sending emails. Remember [Separation of Concerns (SoC).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

In fact, a library already exists to do this for you, called [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Comment: Actually the method name is a misnomer - its sole function it to email details of the error.

Comment: That still doesn't change my point, which is separation of concerns.

Comment: I think my reluctance to use App_Code folder stems from bad experiences with the Website template. Going with your suggestion but cannot get intellisense in master page code behind when calling new class method in App_Code folder

Comment: Make sure you class is set to Compile, not Content. (Right click the class and go to properties in the Solution Explorer).

Comment: Did that and also set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy Always'. Still no intellisense...

Comment: I'm going to go with your suggestion of putting it in a library. Thanks for your help mason, marking as answer :-)

Comment: When you tried the App_Code method, did you remember to add a using statement with the namespace to your master page code behind so that it can see the class?

Comment: No, I just used the full path where I was calling it (starting with the static class name).

Comment: That's probably what your problem was. By default when you place code in a folder the namespace will be `DefaultNamespace.FolderName`.

Comment: You may be right mason but I usually avoid App_Code folder with WAPs http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend NLog for your purposes. It allows for configurable logging, including via SMTP. Your code would look like:

```
using Nlog;

public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static Logger bpLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public void LogError(Exception error)
    {
        bpLogger.LogException(
            LogLevel.Error,
            "ruh roh",
            error
        );

        ...
        //smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Because NLog is pretty efficient, you can instantiate a private static `Logger` object per page you are logging on. Additionally, the logger will automatically record which class it came from, and various configuration options allow you to change where it logs, how it logs and when it logs without changing any other code.

Here is a link to the configuration for sending errors via SMTP, for example:

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target

It's a mature project that has been around for a very long time and can grow with your project as your logging needs grow.

Comment: I apologize for the bad method name - there is no logging involved, simply error email notification.